# Excel Pivot Table or VLOOKUP

Tags: spreadsheet, pivot-table, resources

Students have an ID, Name, and English Level in one spreadsheet.  They have an ID and achievement on a standardized test on another spreadsheet.

I need to match the ID's and put the English level into the standardized test results.

I was under a deadline and actually accomplished this by importing into mysql and running update queries BUT I think there has to be an easier way with Excel or Open Office.

Any links to a good tutorial?  I've watched videos and read about pivot tables but I'm not having any luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's a bunch of links:

- [Productivity Portfolio](http://www.timeatlas.com/5_minute_tips/chunkers/learn_to_use_pivot_tables_in_excel_2007_to_organize_data)
- [Ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/excel-pivot-tables.htm)
- [Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/pivottable-reports-101-HA001034632.aspx)
- [About.com](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/datamanagementinexcel/ss/8912pivot_table.htm)
- [Lacher](http://www.lacher.com/toc/tutpiv.htm)
- [Free Training Tutorial](http://www.free-training-tutorial.com/pivot-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you managed to get your head around querys then vlookups should be easy for you.

```
Sheet1
ID, Name, English Level

Sheet2
Id, Achievement
```

Add a new column at the end of sheet 2 - english level with 
    =vlookup(A2,Sheet1!A:C,3,false)

To explain, "**A2**" this says I want to match on the value in A2 (this will change for each row. Then this says "**Sheet1!A:C**", the data I'm interested in is in Sheet 1, columns A:C. The "**3**" says you want the value in the third column in sheet1 A:C. And finally the "**False**" says, the data won't be in order - if you sort it, and set this to be true you will get better performance results.